# Missing Webforms for Marketers Data

Tags: sitecore, sitecore6, web-forms-for-marketers

I'm attempting to troubleshoot a Sitecore system that has the Webforms for Marketers module installed.

I have submitted a contact form from the front-end but when I look at the form reports, there is only legacy data on the "Data" tab. If I look in the "Usability Report" tab, I can indeed see my submitted data.

There are several save actions set up, one of which is the Save to Database, and another is Send Mail. Neither seem to be firing.

Since the data is under the Usability report, it would seem that something is working but I'm not sure how to troubleshoot where the issue originates from.

One key piece of info is the site has recently been moved from one server to another. The connection strings work as far as I can tell, however. Also, there is no CD/CM separation, just a Master => Web publishing setup, though it seems like at one time before I got my hands on it, there was a staging server. Like I said though, the connection strings seem in order.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Turns out I think it did have to do with a previous staging server. I removed the following from `ConnectionStrings.config`

```
<add name="remoteWfmService" connectionString="url=http://{mysite}/sitecore%20modules/shell/Web%20Forms%20for%20Marketers/Staging/WfmService.asmx;user={myuser};password={mypass};timeout=60000"/>
```

Once that came out, everything started working as expected.